# how to get a record in Access form using a text box if there are multi record with different date

Tags: ms-access

i would like to get a full record while searching through a mobile number and last recent Date

with below code i am able to get record but not conditionally as date wise as i am looking for and do't know how to apply my condition to get the output. if trying sql query getting error while using condition.

Here, Table name is :Service_MasterData, column name is: [Mobile Number], Service_Registration_Number, Date

```
prefixtext = txt_mbno.Text
     DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
     DoCmd.GoToControl ("[Mobile Number]")
     DoCmd.FindRecord prefixtext

    Service_Registration_Number.SetFocus
    assetidref = [Mobile Number]
    [Mobile Number].SetFocus
    strSearch = [Mobile Number].Text

    If assetidref = strSearch Then
         MsgBox " !!! Welcome Back "
```

Edited as suggested ..

```
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
    DoCmd.GoToControl ("[Mobile Number]")

    strCriteria = "[Mobile Number] = " & Me![txt_mbno]
    rst.FindFirst strCriteria ' here shows data type error
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    Service_Registration_Number.SetFocus
    assetidref = [Mobile Number]
    [Mobile Number].SetFocus
    strSearch = [Mobile Number].Text
    Me.Service_ID.Value = ""
    Me.Service_Token_No.Value = ""
    Me.Engine_Power.Value = ""

    If assetidref = strSearch Then
         MsgBox " !!! Welcome Back "
```

Comment: Don't use FindRecord. Review https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/667899-finding-specific-record-programmatically

Comment: Actually here i had used to find a specific record with only a mobile number which is working find .. i have gone through the shared link but bit confuse what to apply ... here i want to check the last dated entry with this mobile number and get the record in form..

Comment: You want multiple parameters and as far as I can see, FindRecord does not allow that (I have never used FindRecord). I usually use method 3 described in link.

Comment: sorry tried using the same parameter as its described in 3. but giving data type error.         i have posted that code in above body..

Comment: one more assistance i am able to get the recent date , kindly assist how can i get the record in the form with mobile no & Date ...hope you understand i am trying to convey

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Mobile Number] is a text type field, use apostrophe delimiters.

```
strCriteria = "[Mobile Number] = '" & Me![txt_mbno] & "'"
```

Date/Time type uses # delimiter, no delimiter for number type.